# Doctrine arraycollection keeps being null

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Hey Im just trying out doctrine for php alittle and i got an issue with my $matches arraycollection, when i set it in the __construct it works but afterwards its just null and i cant seem to figure out why, the other arraycollections works perfectly

```
<?php
// src/Player.php
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="teams")
 **/
class Team
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
     **/
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     **/
    protected $name;
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Player", mappedBy="team")
     **/
    protected $players;
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Goal",mappedBy="againstTeam")
     **/
    protected $goalsAgainst;
    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     **/
    protected $color;
    /**
     * ManyToMany(targetEntity="Match", mappedBy="teams")
     **/
    protected $matches;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->matches = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->players = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->goalsAgainst = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getMatches() {
        return $this->matches;
    }

    public function addMatch(Match $match) {
        $this->matches->add($match);       
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function setColor($color) {
        $this->color = $color;
    }

    public function addGoalsAgainst(Goal $goal) {
        $this->goalsAgainst->add($goal);
        $goal->setAgainstTeam($this);
    }

    public function getJson() {
        return array(
            'Id'=>$this->id,
            'Name'=>$this->name,
            'Players'=>null,
            'GoalsAgainst'=>null,
            'Color'=>$this->color,
            'Matches'=>null
        );
    }
}
?>
```

if i add an nullcheck to the addMatches(Match $match) like

```
public function addMatch(Match $match) {
    if ($this->matches == null) {
        $this->matches = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    $this->matches->add($match);
}
```

then the match is added but if i then at next line uses $team->getMatches() then the $matches is null again

Comment: Missing annotation `ManyToMany(targetEntity="Match", mappedBy="teams")` should be `@ManyToMany(targetEntity="Match", mappedBy="teams")` assuming proper path association in your annotation reader.

Comment: Also for your `getJson` method, I suggest you use a proper Serializer, so you do not break the associations.  Something like [Symfony Serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/serializer.html) or [JMSerializer](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer)

Comment: @fyrye thanks, wonder how ive missed that one, ive tried to copy paste it a couple times from other classes having a ManyToMany but must have missed that @ all the times lol. 

I'll try looking into a proper serializer later, now i just want to learn using doctrine :)